# Fast way to grep gzipped files in reverse piped to tail/head

Tags: linux, bash, grep, gzip, cat

I need to search a folder of gzipped files for a string, however I need to search starting at the bottom of each file.  I then need the command to return results when it has 10 matches.

So far I have this:

```
find '/tmp/myfiles/' -type f \( -iname '*.txt' -o -iname '*.gz' \) -exec zcat -f {} \+ 2>&1 | tac | zgrep -ish 'foobar' | tail -n +1 | head -n 10
```

I'm using `zcat` to get all the file contents, and then I use `tac` to reverse them. This is significantly slower than this:

```
find '/tmp/myfiles/' -type f \( -iname '*.txt' -o -iname '*.gz' \) -exec zgrep -ish 'foobar' {} \+ 2>&1 | tail -n +1 | head -n 10
```

However this only reads from the top of the file, I'd like a way to search in reverse without having to read the full file first...

Comment: Maybe better asked at [unix.se] SE?

Comment: Do you mean you want the last 10 matches in each file, or when the total number of matches across all the files reaches 10, so maybe 6 in the first file and then 4 in the second?

Comment: `when the total number of matches across all the files reaches 10, so maybe 6 in the first file and then 4 in the second? `

This :)

Comment: Why do you run `zgrep` on a stream which apparently isn't compressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to avoid reading the beginning of the file. But reversing the entire file just to get the last matches is obviously significantly slower than reversing just the matches (unless every line contains a match, of course). Maybe try this;

```
find '/tmp/myfiles/' -type f \( -iname '*.txt' -o -iname '*.gz' \) -exec zgrep -ish 'foobar' {} \+ 2>&1 | tac | head -n 10
```